# Parenscipt not compiling valid expression?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, parenscript

I have this parenscript macro:

```
;;;  Parenscript macro for showModal() and close() methods for pop-up dialogs.
;;;Takes the dialog's id, button for opening the dialog's id, and closing button's id.
(defpsmacro open-close-modal-dialog (dialog-id element-id-1 element-id-2 &key open close open-args close-args)
     (let ((dialog (ps-gensym)))
       `(progn
          (setf ,dialog (chain document (get-element-by-id ,dialog-id)))
          (setf (chain document (get-element-by-id ,element-id-1) onclick)
                (lambda (,@open-args)
                  (progn
                    ,@open
                    (funcall (chain ,dialog show-modal)))))
          (setf (chain document (get-element-by-id ,element-id-2) onclick)
                (lambda (,@close-args)
                  (progn
                    ,@close
                    (funcall (chain ,dialog close))))))))
```

And I'm using it in a Hunchentoot handler like so:

```
(define-easy-handler (student-name :uri "/student-info") (name)
  (let ((student (student-from-name name)))
    (standard-page (:title "Ashtanga Yoga Osaka | Student Page"
                           :script (ps
                                     (defun init ()
                                       (open-close-modal-dialog "editPassDialog" "getPass" "submitPass"
                                                                       ;; This is the pop-up dialog
                                                                :open (ps(defvar frm (chain document (get-element-by-id "editPass"))))))
                                     (setf (chain window onload) init)))
      ;; Main form
      (:form :action "/edit-student" :method "post" :id "editStudent"
             (:p "Name" (:input :type "text" :name "name" :class "txt" :value (format nil "~A" (name student))))
             (:P "Email" (:input :type "email" :name "email" :class "txt" :value (format nil "~A" (email student))))
             (:p "Passes" (:select :name "passlist" 
                                   (dolist (pass (pass student))
                                     (htm
                                      (:option :id "pass" :value (pass->json pass)
                                               (fmt "~A ~A" (print-month (getf pass :date))
                                                    (print-year (getf pass :date)))))))
                 (:button :type "button" :id "getPass" :class "btn" "Get Pass"))
             (:input :type "hidden" :name "previous" :value nil) ; previous value of the pass
             (:input :type "hidden" :name "old-name" :value name) ; old name of student, used for retrieving the correct instance
             (:p (:input :type "submit" :value "Edit Info" :class "btn")))
      ;; Pop-up dialog for editing passes
      (:dialog :id "editPassDialog"
               (:h1 "Edit Pass")
               (:form :action "#" :method "post" :id "editPass"
                      (:p "Date bought" (:input :type "text" :name "date" :class "txt"))
                      (:p "Type" (:input :type "text" :name "type" :class "txt"))
                      (:p "Amount Paid" (:input :type "text" :name "amt"))
                      (:p (:button :type "button" :class "btn" :id "submitPass" "Edit Pass")))))))
```

Now when I load the system through Quicklisp, I get this error:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of
;   (PS
;     (DEFUN INIT # ...)
;     (SETF #)).
;   Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
;   
;    The Parenscript form (DEFVAR FRM
;                           (CHAIN DOCUMENT
;                            (GET-ELEMENT-BY-ID
;                             editPass))) cannot be compiled into an expression.
```

Which is strange, because I can define this form in the REPL:

```
SHALA-SYS> (macroexpand-1 '(ps (defvar frm (chain document (GET-ELEMENT-BY-ID "editPass")))))
"var frm = document.getElementById('editPass');"
```

And if I remove the `:open` and it's arguments, the system loads, then I add `:open` and args back in and recompile the handler and it compiles without a problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you have both the `defpsmacro` and the use of the defined macro in the same file. I haven't had the time to dig into parenscript code deep enough to understand what exactly goes wrong with the order of evaluation, but the end result is that, when compiling the file, the macro definition does not exist at the time of the 'compilation' of the `ps` form.

As a solution, move your parenscript macros into a separate file and make your other code files depend on it.

As a side note, the `(ps ...)` form on the `:open` keyword argument is unnecessary - the `open` parameter is already expanded *inside* parenscript code in your macro. Additionally, `,@` is incorrect at the expansion of `open` as well - and these two bugs happen to cancel each other.

```
(progn
  ,@open
  (funcall (chain ,dialog show-modal)))
;; with :open (ps (foo)) expands to
"ps; foo(); dialog.showModal();"
;; and with :open (foo) expands to
"foo; dialog.showModal();"

(progn
  ,open
  (funcall (chain ,dialog show-modal)))
;; would expand :open (ps (foo)) to
"ps(foo()); dialog.showModal();"
;; and :open (foo) to
"foo(); dialog.showModal();"
;; which is what you intended.
```

Also, `funcall` is not necessary in that piece of code; you could simply use `(chain ,dialog (show-modal))`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems I didn't (still don't) understand how the `defpsmacro` works. Changing that with a normal `defmacro` wrapped in a `ps` form solved the problem.

So the macro code is now:

```
(ps (defmacro open-close-modal-dialog (dialog-id element-id-1 element-id-2 &key open close open-args close-args)
      (let ((dialog (ps-gensym)))
        `(progn
           (setf ,dialog (chain document (get-element-by-id ,dialog-id)))
           (setf (chain document (get-element-by-id ,element-id-1) onclick)
                 (lambda (,@open-args)
                   (progn
                     ,@open
                     (funcall (chain ,dialog show-modal)))))
           (setf (chain document (get-element-by-id ,element-id-2) onclick)
                 (lambda (,@close-args)
                   (progn
                     ,@close
                     (funcall (chain ,dialog close)))))))))
```

If any **ParenScript** expert can explain what was wrong I'd be much obliged.